# Connection error while creating a basic SpringBoot app with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

So i'm trying to create basic SpringBoot app with DB connectivity and here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://sql.somehost.net:3306/thisismydbname
spring.datasource.username=sql9XXXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXXXX   
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

I created a very basic SpringBoot app with Spring Data JPA and maybe Spring Web dependencies.

When I try to boot up the app, I get the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sql9XXXXXX'@'ip6x-xxx-xx-xxx.dc.dc.cox.net' (using password: YES)
```

When I try to connect to MySQL using MySQL Workbench externally this works fine. Also, it's very weird why it's trying to use my ISP Cox in the connection. I don't know how it picked up my ISP details. I do have the somehost.net where my MySQL is hosted.

Comment: Can you login in mysql in console using this credentials ?

Comment: didnt try the console but from MySQL Workbench, yes i was able to

Comment: Probaly the user is not allowed to connect from another IP then localhost / 127.0.0.1 -> something like GRANT ALL ON thisismydbname.* TO slq9XXX@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'XXXX'; will grant the access to the user.

At least to check it out, afterwards you will need to make it less wildcardy

Comment: So I did try to do a get call (SELECT * from) from another node service and that works. Does the GRANT ALL apply in that case as well?

Comment: Let me explain what the GRANT ALL does. It gives the user slq9XXX the right to access all tables in the database 'thisismydbname' from any source (% wildcard), So it can be another node or coming from your local computer.

Comment: @p0tta, this is your best friend https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/access-control.html start here, MySQL takes host (ip/name) with username